# How can i solve this probability problem fast?

Tags: probability

We have a box and we have on it 6 balls with numbers from 0 to 5. We push out 3 balls in the way that after pushing out a ball we turn it back again in the box. What is the probability that the sum of the numbers will be equal to 5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "fast"? Short? Most people will answer with the easiest and shortest approach.

Comment: i mean in a way that i dont have to count them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_1+x_2+x_3=5,~0 \le x \le 5~,x \in \mathbb{N}$ solution number is $\binom{5+2}{2}=21$

Answer is $\frac{21}{6.6.6}$.

Comment: my idea is to find a way to solve this in a general way. so the right question will be this: if i have n balls with numbers with from 0 to n-1 and i push out three one by one returning it to the box each time. what is the probability of their sum equal to n-1 or the largest number that exists??

Comment: can you please explain me how you find the 21??

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- How many sequences of 3 balls could you get? (call this $n$)
- How many sequences generate a sum of $5$ (e.g. 1,1,3)? (call this $m$)

Your probability is $m/n$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $6^{3}$ possibilities. $(4,0,5)$ is an example. Count by how many of these $(a,b,c)$ we have $a+b+c=5$

Edit:
Start with $5+2=7$ zeros on a row: $0000000$. By replacing two of the zeros by a $1$ you will get for instance $0010100$ representing the summation $5=2+1+2$. This is picking out $2$ out of $7$ so there are $\left({7\atop 2}\right)=21$ ways to do that.

Comment: i need a way not to count them

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: Thank you this link could help

Comment: where did you get the 2

Comment: number $5$ must be split up in $3$ parts. This is done by placing $3-1=2$ borders. (the two numbers $1$ are these borders here)